# Difference between CONCUR_UPDATABLE and RowSet

Tags: java, jdbc

Are there any difference(advantages or disadvatages) between using CONCURE_UPDATABLE and JDBCRowSet to make changes to the database?

1.

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery("select * from book");
        set.absolute(2);
        set.deleteRow();
```

2.

```
    RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
    JdbcRowSet rowSet = factory.createJdbcRowSet();
    .....
    rowSet.setCommand("select * from book");
    rowSet.execute();

    rowSet.absolute(2);
    rowSet.deleteRow();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All RowSet objects are by default scrollable and updatable. If the driver and database being used do not support scrolling and/or updating of result sets, an application can populate a JdbcRowSet object with the data of a ResultSet object and then operate on the JdbcRowSet object as if it were the ResultSet object. - from enthuware